# Rocket League offline or single player

Tags: steam, rocket-league

My 6yo son wants to play Rocket League, but my 16yo doesn't want him to mess with his online ranking or whatever it's called.  It appears the current release of Rocket League doesn't have offline or single-player matches available anymore.  Have we missed something somewhere?

How can we let the younger son play rocket league in single-player so that it doesn't affect the older brother's online ranking and matches?  It has a training mode, but there don't appear to be any AI players, which I think used to be there previously.

Rocket League, fully updated, on Steam, Windows 10.

Comment: There is a game mode for playing casual games rather than ranked games. If you have your six year old play in that mode it won't have any effect on your sixteen year old's online rank

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Rocket League is now free on the Epic Games Store](https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/product/rocket-league/home). You can create the younger son his own account to play on.  He can play online and earn his own rank, without affecting the older son's rank.  You can disable chat in the options, if you're worried about that.

If you still don't want him playing online, the single player modes can be found under
**Play --> Custom Games --> Exhibition**
and
**Play --> Custom Games --> Season**

Comment: Note that because of COPPA, the 6-year-old cannot have their own account on most sites, including Steam and Epic. This answer, however, would work for the OP creating their own account and letting the 6-yo use it via a Parental Controls PIN.

Comment: @TheHansinator What is COPPA?  Is that some American rule?  I'm not keen for him to have an account anyway, and probably would cause more issues with relogging each time rather than a few mouse-clicks

Comment: Thanks for this answer - the second part Custom Games > Exhibition etc. looks like exactly what we're after.  I've shown the teen and he seems happy with it and said he'd allow the kid to use his RL account.  So that's a win!

Comment: @Midavalo Yes, COPPA is American - it stands for the Children's Online Privacy Protection Act and restricts personal data collection of children under 13. In practice this means that most online services do not allow children under 13 to create accounts with them, and the sites that do are extremely limited in what data they ask for.